# Pattern Lab: "Your styleguide won't render because i can't find your styleguide files...."

Tags: php, frontend, mustache, patternlab.io

I was trying to generate the Pattern Lab site after their new upgrade, however, after I downloaded all the dependencies, it kept complaining that my style guide won't render because the styleguide files cannot be found at patternlab-php-master\vendor/pattern-lab/styleguidekit-mustache-default, and it suggested me to fix this in ./config/config.yml by editing styleguideKitPath... I checked the ./config/config.yml file and the path appears to match the folder where the styleguide files are stored. I couldn't figure out what's wrong, and also, what are the style files? Because when I looked into the styleguidekit-mustache-default, I have what is shown in the picture below, but I don't know if they are all that's needed or not. If someone is experienced in the new version of Pattern Labs or knows how to solve this problem please let me know. Thank you!
[styleguidekit-mustache-default content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo8k6.png)

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue which was resolved by updating the following in the config.yml file /config/config.yml:

1. the 'styleguideKit' variable to  "pattern-lab/styleguidekit-mustache-default" i.e. the path to the    styleguide kit from within the "vendor" folder in your project root.
2. the 'styleguideKitPath' variable to "vendor/pattern-lab/styleguidekit-mustache-default" i.e. the path to the styleguide kit from within the project root.

My config.yml file had the full path when I first opened it and half of the slashes

Hope this helps.